# How to have low TTFB in request to nodejs and s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I have nodejs application. I'm using to serve images from aws-s3 using `aws-sdk`.

The problem is the request to the image taking too long (waiting time in the picture - the green bar)

[image]
Here my handler function for access S3 and sending the response:

```
router.get('/image/:fileKey', (req, res) => {
  const Key = req.params.fileKey;

  const options = {
    Bucket: config.bucket,
    Key,
  };

  s3.getObject(options)
    .on('httpHeaders', function(code, headers) {
      if (code < 300) {
        res.set(
          _.pick(headers, 'content-type', 'content-length', 'last-modified')
        );
      }
    })
    .createReadStream()
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log({ err });
      res.status(404).end();
    })
    .pipe(res);
});
```

Is there a way to optimize the request to having lower **waiting time**?

Comment: I would start by benchmarking this code.  Log the current time immediately before `s3.getObject()` and then inside the `on('httpHeaders'...` handler function.  Calculating the difference between those two timestamps will give you a value that is very close to the true TTFB *from S3 to the server*... and I'd suggest that your next course of action depends fairly heavily on what you observe here, compared to what you see at the browser.  Also useful to capture would be the repeatability of the timing across subsequent requests without restarting the Node process, and then with restarts.